# Excel formula needed to change interlinked values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm having 4zones with 100% business mix.
Let's suppose
Zone1 = 40%
Zone2= 15%
Zone3= 25%
Zone4= 20%

I want to know formula for below:
interchange% manually for 1 or 2 zones but rest zone have to adjust by itself to make it total 100%

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems.

Comment: I believe you may need VBA to do this. It's unclear what you want exactly. some sample data, expected outcome and what you have tried so far would be useful

Comment: You also need to tell us how to distribute the remaining % to the 2 or 3 unknown zones. But if you knew that you could probably solve this yourself. This may be possible with formulas, but the output will have to be in different cells from the zone input.

Answer (score 0):

You pick one of the Zones to be your catch-all, Zone 4 perhaps.

Then you write a formula for it like so:

```
=1 - sum(Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3)
```

Of course, you suit it to your circumstances. Perhaps you want to enter literal numbers as if they were percentages:  80 instead of 80% or 0.8. In that case you use 100 right after the `=` instead of the 1. And naturally, you need cell addresses instead of "Zone 1" and so on.

(I do not get the idea you know what Named Ranges are so I say that. If you do, or know how to use the `LET` function, you can give them names instead, but somewhere you DO have to specify the cell addresses.)

So basically, the formula lets you enter whatever you wish for the other three Zones, and subtracts their total from 1 (or 100) so the four together always add up to 1 (or 100).

You may be realizing that things could go south if someone enters values exceeding 1 (or 100) in the other Zones... that would make the dumping bucket give a NEGATIVE value which doesn't seem like a desirable thing. You can set some basic error checking like so:

```
=IF( 1 - sum(Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3) < 0, "Check your entries!", 1 - sum(Zone 1, Zone 2, Zone 3) )
```

This formula says that IF the value is less than 0, the display "Check your entries!" in the Zone 4 cell but if it is not less than 0, then display the result you expect.

You could make it more complicated than that. Maybe you want to have two Zones that act as buckets, and maybe they don't split the remainder in two, but proportion it some-else-how. You could even have it change on the fly for different kinds of things being tracked. But the above formulas do the job and the second gives very basic, but completely sufficient, value error checking. (Values, not other stuff. So if someone enters "Texas prison millipede" in a cell that number values are expected in, this error checking won't catch it except in quite old versions of Excel.)